# How to direct to another page after running query

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can I create something like that after running a query?

```php
if($query)
{
  succes.php;
}
else
{
  fail.php;
}
```

Tried this but didn't work either..

```php
$url = '../modul_produk/index.php';
$url2 = '../modul_produk/index2.php';
if($query)
{
    header('Location: ' . $url);
}
else
{
 header('Location: ' . $url2);
}
```

I get this error

> Notice: Undefined variable: query in >C:\xampp\htdocs\Payang\modul_daftar\index4.php on line 148
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output >started at C:\xampp\htdocs\Payang\modul_daftar\index4.php:126) in >C:\xampp\htdocs\Payang\modul_daftar\index4.php on line 153

line 126 is refer to `?php`

line 148 and 153 both refer to the `$url` and the header..

What I don't get it is why is the `?php` deem as a header? How can I fix this? Tried all of the mention answer and it seems the problem is at the `?php` as mention in the error at line 126.

For the ref this is the full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Sistem Laporan Bersepadu</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/darkly/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function uploadImage(oForm) {
  var _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png"];
  var oInput = document.getElementById("image");
  var sFileName = oInput.value;
  var size = oInput.files[0].size;   
  
  var oFReader = new FileReader();
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("image").files[0]);
  oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
   document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
  };
  
  if (sFileName.length > 0) {
   var blnValid = false;
   for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
    var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
    if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
     blnValid = true;
     break;
    }
   }    
   if (!blnValid) {
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="<span class='label label-danger'>Tidak Sah</span>";
    document.getElementById("submitBtn").disabled = true;
    return false;
   }
  }   
  if(size > 4294967295){
   document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="<span class='label label-danger'>Tidak Sah</span>";
   document.getElementById("submitBtn").disabled = true;
   return false;
  }else {   
   document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML="<span class='label label-success'>Sah</span>.";
   document.getElementById("submitBtn").disabled = false;
   return true;    
  }
  }
  </script> 
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
   <h2>Borang Pendaftaran</h2>
   <h5>Sila Isi Semua Maklumat</h2>
   
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span> Borang untuk pelapor</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <form id="produkForm" action="../modul_kemaskini/index.php" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
      <fieldset>          
                  
       
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputKodProduk" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Kod Produk</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputKodProduk" id="inputKodProduk" placeholder="KodProduk">
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputNamaProduk" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nama Produk</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputNamaProduk" id="inputNamaProduk" placeholder="NamaProduk">
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputSpesifikasi" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Spesifikasi</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputSpesifikasi" id="inputSpesifikasi" placeholder="Spesifikasi">
        </div>
       </div>
      
         
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="selectJenis" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Jenis</label>
         <div class="col-lg-10">
          <select class="form-control" id="selectJenis" name="selectJenis">
           <option value="silapilih">Sila Pilih</option>
           <option value="Telefon">Telefon</option>
           <option value="Tv">Tv</option>
           <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
          </select>
         </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputHarga" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Harga</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputHarga" id="inputHarga" placeholder="RM">
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Gambar</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
         <img src="" id="uploadPreview" class="img-responsive" style="height: 100px;" />
         <input type="file" name="image" id="image" onchange="uploadImage(this)">
        </div>
       </div>
       
       
       
       <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2"> 
          
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
         <div id="alert"></div>        
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <?php 
       if (isset($_POST['submit']))
       {    
        include '../include/conn.php';
                
        $kod=$_POST['inputKodProduk'] ;
        $namaproduk= $_POST['inputNamaProduk'] ;     
        $spesifikasi=$_POST['inputSpesifikasi'] ;
        $jenis=$_POST['selectJenis'] ;
        $harga=$_POST['inputHarga'] ;
        $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image= file_get_contents($image);
        $image= base64_encode($image);
     
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `produk2`
        (product_code,product_name,product_desc,product_type,product_price,product_img,product_img_name) 
        VALUES ('$kod','$namaproduk','$spesifikasi','$jenis','$$harga','$image','$name')");
       }
       if($query)
{
    $url = '../modul_produk/index.php';
}
else
{
    $url = '../modul_produk/index2.php';
}

header('Location: ' . $url);
exit();
        
        
   
    
   
       ?>
       
       
      
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>

 
            
    
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are two problems.

1. Calling the `header()` function sends HTTP headers. These contain some metadata about server request and instructs the browser what to do with the response, in your case display a different page. They [must be sent as the first thing](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039) in the response, otherwise it's too late for the browser to interpret them.

   In your case, the server first sends `<!DOCTYPE html>...` and it's too late then for sending headers. You must call `header()` *before* any output is made. This includes sending HTML, calling `echo ...` or even sending error message (`Notice: ...` in your case`)

   What to do about it? The simplest solution is to move call to `header()` earlier in the script. Put

   ```
      <?php    
          if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {      
             include '../include/conn.php';

             $kod=$_POST['inputKodProduk'] ;
             //....
             $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `produk2`
               (product_code,product_name,product_desc,product_type,product_price,product_img,product_img_name) 
               VALUES ('$kod','$namaproduk','$spesifikasi','$jenis','$$harga','$image','$name')");
             if($query) {}
               $url = '../modul_produk/index.php';
             } else {
               $url = '../modul_produk/index2.php';
             }
             header('Location: ' . $url);
             exit();
          }
     ?>
   ```

   as *the very first thing* in your script. A comprehensive description how to deal with this problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/2032064).
2. Another problem is the `Notice: Undefined variable: query` error. If `isset($_POST['submit']))` is evaluated to false, variable `$query` is not initialized. You probably want to move your `if($query)` if block inside `if(isset($_POST['submit'])))` if block, as in the example I gave in above. Otherwise the notice message will be sent to the browser and it may mess up sending headers too.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are sending `header` twice in the same file. Try storing the URL in a variable using conditional statement and only setting the header once instead. Something like this might work:

```
if($query)
{
    $url = '../modul_produk/index.php';
}
else
{
    $url = '../modul_produk/index2.php';
}

header('Location: ' . $url);
exit();
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code of the page? There must be something else that's already sending the header information from the page.

Answer (score 0):

Is the url you are referring to a internal page or external page on Internet? if its a external page, then I would agree with @Rino Raj but if its a internal page, all you need is the header('Location:thepage.php');

Comment: its an internal page. and i already triend (location:page.php') but like the updated question, the problems is at line 126 that is <?php

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
$url = '../modul_produk/index.php';
$url2 = '../modul_produk/index2.php';
if($query)
{
    header("Location: ${url}");
}
else
{
 header("Location: ${url2}");
}
```

---

you need to do a little change in your code, move the

```
if($query)...
```

inside the

```
if(isset($_POST['session']))
```

Comment: tried it and still the same problems Notice: Undefined variable: query in C:\xampp\htdocs\Payang\modul_daftar\index4.php on line 146

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\Payang\modul_daftar\index4.php:126) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Payang\modul_daftar\index4.php on line 154

Answer (score 0):

First check your code at 148 what is undefined, please define it, if that is not possible , just do a ob_start() in top of the file , that should suppress the buffer header already sent warning, and should redirect you in desired page.

and also please add a exit() or die() after the header location code.